# how to monitor if a file size not change do something in ubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitoring, monit

the goal is that if my *file.log* size does not change in 10 minutes then send two HTTP requests to some servers. something like this:

```
check file.log 
if not change in 10 min
send HTTP request to http://my_url:8008 with username:admin and password:admin
send HTTP request to http://my_url:8009
```

so what efficient way to do that? use script? any monitoring tools?

Comment: Look into basic bash scripting and `curl`.

Comment: Not a question for this Ubuntu support site.